# Defining descending index in entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

Is there any built in way to define a descending index in entity framework 6.1? IndexAttribute and DbMigration's CreateIndex method allow only to create ascending indexes. And I don't want to use raw sql for this.

Comment: Pathetic they stopped work on EF6 and diverted all resources to EF7 w/o making EF6 complete for basic SQL stuff.